# Clarification with join tables needed

Tags: sql, database, database-design, erd

In the attached image, you can see a m:n relationship in the ERD.

Since it's a m:n relationship, my understanding is that a join table is needed.

But, I'm confused about how to implement this.

I created the tables 'Department' and 'Role' with the attributes from the image, and a join table called 'Department_Roles' which combines the PKs from 'Department' and 'Role'.

But, I don't understand how to fill in the 'Role' table. I end up needing to repeat Role_ID to cater for the same Role_ID with different Department_ID's. But this isn't allowed without using a composite key, and I thought the join table was supposed to solve this problem, but I'm still left with the 'Role' table that I can't fill in without repeating Role_ID.

What do I do?

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd6yT.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?.. Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: You need to remove the Role.Department_ID column

Comment: @mathshelp show me what you have